# MS Project not showing proper dates when importing XML generated using mpxj library

Tags: java, xml, ms-project, mpxj

I am using mpxj lib (5.2.2) to export a project to xml using ProjectWriter for mpp (MS Project). Am setting the ***duration, actual duration, start date, finish date, resume date, percentComplete , actualStartDate , actualFinishDate*** wherever applicable but whatever I do, when I finally import the file in MS Project 2016, its showing different finish dates for the tasks.

Please [click here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8vfuujUF4uAaEdTTG9ZdEpIclE) to check the xml being imported

I would like to know what other properties should be set to the task and the project tags for MS Project to show the correct dates that are present in the file. Also, even when the calendar in the xml says all days are working days, the calendar in MS Project after importing still has 5 day work week. The exceptions are getting imported correctly. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a few things here:

1. If you import a start date and duration, the finish date has to be accurate otherwise something has to change. Either import start and duration or start and finish.
2. If you have actual dates, no need for start and finish as they are over-written.
3. Changing Saturday and Sunday to working days is not about exceptions (use them for holidays). You need to edit working hours.